# remove Editext views created dynamically

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have created my views `programmatically` using the below code

method to create edittext

```
 private View newedittext() {
    final EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
    params.setMargins(0, 30, 0, 0);
    editText.setLayoutParams(params);


    editText.setId(count++);
    editText.setTextSize(14);
    editText.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
    editText.setMaxEms(2);
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    return editText;
}
```

method to create an imageview

```
  public ImageView newImageview(Context context) {
    final ImageView imgView = new ImageView(context);
    imgView.setOnClickListener(this);
    imgView.setId(count);
    imgView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_close_red));
    return imgView;
}
```

inside my oncreateview fragment

```
 Button btnad = (Button) child.findViewById(R.id.btnad);
                btnad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                        layout.addView(newedittext());
                        layout.addView(newImageview(getActivity()));
                        lnrView.addView(layout);
                    }
                });
```

on click of imageview here i want to remove the edittext view

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clicked" + v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

[image]
How to remove an `edittext` having a particular id on a  click can any one help me

Comment: have you tried ``yourparentviewGroup.removeView(editText)`` ?

Comment: i am having trouble to get the particular editext object using "id"

Comment: what trouble exactly?

Comment: i dont know how to get the object of editext using id, i searched , but am not understanding

Comment: have you tried ``parentLayout.findViewById(R.id.yourid)`` ?

Comment: no. let me try like that.

Comment: Where is you id defined? You need to use a different id for every generated EditText

Comment: Do you want to remove it or just hide it from the UI?

Comment: i want to remove the view

Comment: Can you please post the part where you remove the view?

Comment: You can try `LinearLayout.removeViewAt(int index)` if you know the index of the child views in the `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this view in your activity and remove it form its parent.

```
private void removeViewWithId(int id) {
    View view = findViewById(id);
    if(view != null){
        ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
        if(parent instanceof ViewGroup){
            ((ViewGroup)parent).removeView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT

After question edditing it look like you want to remove EditText and also ImageView (full row). You can achive it that way:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
    if (parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ((ViewGroup) parent).removeAllViews();
    }
}
```

If you only want to remove EditText, pass id as ImageView tag:

```
Button btnad = (Button) child.findViewById(R.id.btnad);
            btnad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        EditText et = newedittext();
        layout.addView(et);
        ImageView iv = newImageview(getActivity())
        iv.setTag(et.getId());
        layout.addView(iv);
        lnrView.addView(layout);
    }
});
```

And then remove it in onImageViewClick:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Object editTextId = view.getTag();
        if(editTextId == null){
            return;
        }

        ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
        if (parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
            EditText et = ((ViewGroup) parent).findViewById((Integer) editTextId);            
            ((ViewGroup) parent).removeView(et);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i will try your answer